# removes @ symbol in wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to work on a sign up page,

I have completed that and send a mail to the registered user to verify

This mail contains a link like :

```
www.xyz.com/verify?email=xxx@gmil.com
```

but when this url is opened in browser then the `@` symbol stripes out, means the url remains

```
www.xyz.com/verify?email=xxxgmil.com
```

How can I avoid the browser to stripe off the `@` symbol

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Encode your URLs (**@** gets replaced by **%40**)